# How to build a Weighted Graph with Ruby's RGL or GRATR to perform Dijkstra's algorithm?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, graph, rgl

I would like to see an example of a Dijkastra search algorithm for a graph built using Ruby's RGL (http://rgl.rubyforge.org/) or GRATR (http://rubyforge.org/projects/gratr/).

I know GRATR has Dijkastra support but I'm not really sure how to go about using it, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: his last answer was the correct one: "This is an example of dijkstra in GRATR
http://gratr.rubyforge.org/svn/examples/graph_self.rb"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of these should help:

http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/7331
http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/6100
http://github.com/dbrady/dijkstra

This is an example of dijkstra in GRATR
http://gratr.rubyforge.org/svn/examples/graph_self.rb

Comment: It's not really RGL or GRATR, but it's a good help. Thanks Kalyan.